# How to import/upload a WordPress database without access to Cpanel

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I finished a WordPress project. I already uploaded all the files through FTP, now I have to import the database, but the client doesn't want to give me access to Cpanel.

How can I import / upload the database?

My client shared with me database name, database user and database password.

Comment: Would you need to import a database dump written in SQL? If so, what SGBD is the dump from? MySQL/MariaDB? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, MySQL/MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

I see the following alternatives, however they may work or not depending on how the server is configured.

- If the web server has the `mysql` executable installed, you may be able to upload the dump via FTP and run the executable from a temporary PHP script:

```
<?php
passthru ("mysql -h $db_host -D $db_name -u $db_user -p$db_password -e 'source ./dump.sql'", $return_var);
if ($return_var === 0) unlink (__FILE__);
```

- You may be able to run a [temporary installation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install) of [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and use it import the database dump.

Comment: thanks, you saved me a lot of time with this snippet

Answer (score 0):

on top of what Anderson said , I will suggest to try pluggin for migration or backup and restore, so we don't endup in this kind of blocking access issues.

here are two pluggin i use mostly for similar requirement.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/